# Issue in displaying a view from a .aar file in Xamarin forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a .aar file component which has the below functions.

1) Open camera
2) Open gallery
3) Return a string which is given as input
4) Open a new view which displays the passed input string.

I have created an Android binding library for this and referenced in Xamarin Forms Android. I am able to perform the first three operations correctly. But when i call the fourth function, I am getting a dark colour background with actionbar containing projectName.Android text. This actually should show a white colour view with the passed input string as label.

The input params for this method is Context and string. I am passing the correct context because i am getting the correct output from the other three methods. Also when this same .aar library is binded in a native android app, it is showing all methods properly. Can anyone help me whether I am doing anything wrong?

I can share the .aar file/binding library dll/sample code, if required.

Comment: Hi, please share your demo with me. Does there any error?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT - There is no error...instead it is just showing a black screen. If u can share me your mail id, I can share it in google drive and send u the demo

Comment: Sorry, I can't share my mail Id, it will violate company policy. You can remove the sensitive info and upload it on the github.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT - Hi I got the answer. Please see the below answer. I got it working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer. We need to add a JavaDocs folder at the Binding project and copy the JavaDoc files obtained while building the native component to this folder. Then need to add the index.html present in the folder and need to set the build action to JavaDocIndex. Now this binding needs to be build and refer to the android project which will display the view also while calling the method.